# Can I create multiple conditional formatting in google sheets based on data in a certain cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to add some conditional formatting in google sheets.

I want to colour cells based on what text they have in them.

I have 20 different rules that I would need to create, which look like this

[image]

Is there a way of creating conditional formatting that automatically creates conditional formatting based on existing cells without me creating 20 different rules?

Comment: Ofc there is, have you tried looking up [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) on the matter?

Comment: Can you provide the information about `20 different rules`?

Comment: hi @Tanaike, I want to have certain cells to be a certain colour if there a cell has certain words in it. if a cell has the word "NZL", I want to have the cell have a black background and white lettering. I have the rules in a column in the worksheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I have the rules in a column in the worksheet`, I cannot understand about the rules. Can you provide the sample worksheet which has the rules in a column that you want to use as the rules for the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function colors(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  var rules = ss.getRange("A1:A4").getValues();
  var colors = ss.getRange("A1:A4").getBackgrounds();
  var data = ss.getRange("C1:C" + ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var targetColors = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++){
      if (data[i][0] == rules[j][0]){
//        Logger.log("At if - " + targetColors);
        targetColors.push([colors[j][0]]);
        break;
      }
      else if (j == rules.length-1){
//        Logger.log("At else - " + targetColors);
        targetColors.push(["#ffffff"]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
//  Logger.log(targetColors);
  ss.getRange("C1:C" + ss.getLastRow()).setBackgrounds(targetColors);
}
```

This function will get a list of rules and their colors (in A1:A4 in my case) and then the data in the entire column C, keep in mind that this code assumes that the data has more rows than the rules.

Comment: heya, this looks like it's working. would it be possible to select a certain sheet if the file has a lot of sheets within it?

Comment: I updated the code to show you how it would need to be, you just need to use `getSheetByName()` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename))

Answer (score 1):

This code will add a 'Rules' menu to your google sheet that contains a 'Create Conditional Rules' sub-item.

When you select the 'Create Conditional Rules' menu option it will replace the existing conditional format rules in your sheet with 20 conditional format rules. The rules are based on the text,font colour and background colour in the cells in the range A1:A20 in your sheet.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Rules')
      .addItem('Create Conditional Rules', 'createRules')
  .addToUi();
}

function createRules() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rulesRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A20");
  var textValues = rulesRange.getValues();
  var fontColors = rulesRange.getFontColors();
  var backGroundColors = rulesRange.getBackgrounds();
  var rules = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < textValues.length; i++) {
    rules.push(createConditionalFormatRule(sheet, textValues[i], fontColors[i], backGroundColors[i]))
   };
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function createConditionalFormatRule(sheet, textVal, fontColor, backGroundColor) {  
   var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
   var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
   var range = sheet.getRange(1,2,numRows,numCols);
   return SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextEqualTo(textVal)
      .setBackground(backGroundColor)
      .setFontColor(fontColor)
      .setRanges([range])
      .build();
}
```

For example if cell A1 contains:

- text value 'ENG'
- font color red
- background color white

this code adds a conditional rule to the sheet that will set all cells to the right of column "A" that contain the value 'ENG' to font color red and background colour white. The key lines in the code that set up the rule are:

```
      .whenTextEqualTo(textVal)
      .setBackground(backGroundColor)
      .setFontColor(fontColor)
```

The code iterates through all the cells in the column A1:A20 adding a conditional rule based on the content of each cell.

**Notes**:

- For the rules to be created there must be at least one column to the
  right of the "A" column with some text in it.
- If you want to *add* these new rules to the existing rules then change:

```
   var rules = [];
```

- to:

```
   var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
```